# React Router Gives 404 error on production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

React Router works on local machine, Chrome but not on safari and other browsers,

```
 <Switch>
    <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home} />
    <Route path="/programs/:slug" component={Programs} />
    <Route path="/page/:slug" component={Page} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

thats my code but it works perfectly in development mode no errors but on production, safari gives 404 error when i navigate to programs/:slug or page/:slug

Comment: Did you put url rewrite on production. All url should target to `index.html`

Comment: Is it this? I put this in my package.json before build   "homepage": "https://www.example.co"

Comment: I'm using a shared hosting by the way

Comment: On production your application hot running on nodejs which host as single page application. On production you need to put some configuration which depend on server. like in apache you can configure in .htaaccess or in nginx you can put rewrite.

Comment: I'm not familiar with botmap.io. I have put answer. Please mark complete if you found answer.

Answer (score 9):

I added this to .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(assets/?|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Thanks to Kishan Mundha explanation

Answer (score 2):

You may need to configure single entry point `index.html` on server. All url should target to `index.html` and entry point will decide how to render and content based on route.

Comment: how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `pm2 serve`, you can simply add the `--spa` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to ./public_html/.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

found the solution at: How to fix ["404" error when directly accessing a component in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248347/how-to-fix-404-error-when-directly-accessing-a-component-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because your site is a react based SPA (Single Page Application).

When you visit the site via the root / it is automatically loading the index.html which is your application, and then when you visit other pages you never actually leave the index.html page

So it loads in additional data and simulates a browser page change.

However when you make a fresh request for example by going to one of those sub pages directly or hitting refresh while on them  the web server is being requested to serve that file… but the file doesn’t actually exist… hence the 404 error.

The way around this is via redirects, you’ll want to have a _redirects file in your deploy folder that contains

When you run the command to build the project.

npm run build

then simply create a new file _redirect and paste this line

/* /index.html 200

then redeploy the project and it will work fine.